# Product object returns no sale price

Tags: functions

I run a mass discount plugin, lets just say for a -50% price which works in the frontend normally. Also I tested the following scenario in Wordpress 5.5.3, woocommerce both 3.7 and 4.8 and no other plugins.

I have a function to create an xml. In that function I check and get the product parent ids and then the products as objects.

When I try to get the sale price with either
`$product->get_sale_price()`
or print the whole object
`print_r($product)`
the
`[sale_price]`
is empty, the
`[regular_price]`
is empty and the
`[price]`
returns the original price

Obviously, what I want is to run a mass discount and return the sale price of the products in my custom function.

I tried the 2 mass discount plugins 'WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts' and 'Finale Lite'. Then tried with the official themes 2020 and 2021 and with my normal 'Elessi' theme. No results with any plugin/theme/version combination.

I also tried
`$product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );`
which returns the original price.

I guess this is because sale price is product specific. However, why this happens and how could overcome this and show the sale price if a discount is running?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'             => 'product',
  'post_status'           => 'publish',
  'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
  'posts_per_page'        => '1000',
  'tax_query'             => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms'         => 123,
      'operator'      => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
      'field'         => 'slug',
      'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog',
      'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $product = wc_get_product( $query->post->ID );

    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? ( method_exists($product, 'get_parent_id') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_parent() ) : $product->get_id();

    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    $product_price= $product->get_sale_price() ? $product->get_sale_price() : $product->get_price();
    print_r($product);

  endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing much more about your website, theme and plugins, it is not possible to offer any guidance - remember, this is a general WordPress forum - we have no idea how your specific website is setup, so be descriptive in order that people can help.

Comment: You are right @QStudio. I should have provided more info. I just edited to provide more info. However, I tried all combinations and in my experience there was no big difference on the setup and the things I tried. Please do inform me about any other info I should include.

Comment: You will need to show the code for the functions you reference, people can help you find errors in code, but not in how you describe your code.

Comment: WhiteHatMan, the plugins themselves may be storing the sale price elsewhere or they may even be calculating the sale price on the fly as customers are checking out.  If these plugins are overriding WooCommerce prices then there's no reason to expect that you can use standard WooCommerce functions to get the price generated by the plugins. Have you contacted the developers of the plugins?

Comment: @TonyDjukic yes I did contact the developers of 'Finale Lite' and said that I should be able to get the prices with get_sale_price(). I do not have any reason to believe that the other plugin would work in a different way. In the end if you are right about storing the sale price elsewhere, what is the best way to figure it out?